# In the double-slit experiment with single electrons, do some of them hit the screen just behind the material between the two slits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, double-slit-experiment

In the double-slit experiment with single electrons, are there electrons which hit the screen at the spot which is just behind the material between the two slits?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, part of the incident electrons is reflected by the screen.

EDIT (Feb 19, 2023): See, e.g., the animation at https://www.quantamagazine.org/how-our-reality-may-be-a-sum-of-all-possible-realities-20230206/